# Get PropertyName of WPF Control

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a ListBox that I fill with custom objects, these objects have the following properties as seen below:

```
Public Class VariableClass

    Public Property Content As String
    Public Property myNameLabel As New Label
    Public Property myNameTextBox As New ComboBox
    Public Property myTypeLabel As New Label
    Public Property myTypeTextBox As New ComboBox

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Content.ToString()
    End Function

End Class
```

When the user clicks on any of the custom objects, the properties of the custom objects that are WPF controls are pragmatically created in a stackpanel.

I do it like this:

```
            If Flowchart.SelectedItem.GetType.Name = "VariableClass" Then

                SetLabelProperties(Flowchart.SelectedItem.myNameLabel, "Name:", "25", LabelPanel.Width, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                SetLabelProperties(Flowchart.SelectedItem.myTypeLabel, "Type:", "25", LabelPanel.Width, HorizontalAlignment.Center)

                SetComboBoxProperties(Flowchart.SelectedItem.myNameTextBox, Flowchart.SelectedItem.myNameTextBox.Text, "25", ValuePanel.Width, VerticalContentAlignment.Center, True, True)
                SetComboBoxProperties(Flowchart.SelectedItem.myTypeTextBox, Flowchart.SelectedItem.myTypeTextBox.Text, "25", ValuePanel.Width, VerticalContentAlignment.Center, True, True)

                AddPropertiesInStackPanel(Flowchart.SelectedItem)

           End if
```

The functions:

```
 Function SetLabelProperties(myLabel As Label, myName As String, myHeight As String, myWidth As String, myHorizontalAlignment As HorizontalAlignment)

    myLabel.Content = myName
    myLabel.Height = myHeight
    myLabel.Width = myWidth
    myLabel.HorizontalContentAlignment = myHorizontalAlignment

End Function

Function SetComboBoxProperties(myComboBox As ComboBox, myName As String, myHeight As String, myWidth As String, myVerticalAlignment As VerticalAlignment, Editable As Boolean, SearchEnabled As Boolean)

    myComboBox.IsEditable = Editable
    myComboBox.IsTextSearchEnabled = SearchEnabled
    myComboBox.Text = myName
    myComboBox.Height = myHeight
    myComboBox.Width = myWidth
    myComboBox.VerticalContentAlignment = myVerticalAlignment

    Dim myDouble As Double = 0
    Dim myStatic As ResourceKey = SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey
    myComboBox.Resources.Add(myStatic, myDouble)


End Function

Function SetTextBoxProperties(myTextBox As TextBox, myName As String, myHeight As String, myWidth As String, myVerticalAlignment As VerticalAlignment)

    myTextBox.Text = myName
    myTextBox.Height = myHeight
    myTextBox.Width = myWidth
    myTextBox.VerticalContentAlignment = myVerticalAlignment

End Function

Function AddPropertiesInStackPanel(myObject As Object)

    Dim info() As PropertyInfo = myObject.GetType().GetProperties()

    For Each item In info

        Dim myElementSplit = Split(item.PropertyType.FullName, ".")(UBound(Split(item.PropertyType.FullName, ".")))

        If myElementSplit = "Label" Then
            LabelPanel.Children.Add(item.GetValue(myObject))
            LabelPanel.Children.Add(New Separator With {.Height = 1, .Opacity = 0})
        ElseIf myElementSplit = "ComboBox" Then
            ValuePanel.Children.Add(item.GetValue(myObject))
            ValuePanel.Children.Add(New Separator With {.Height = 1, .Opacity = 0})
        ElseIf myElementSplit = "TextBox" Then
            ValuePanel.Children.Add(item.GetValue(myObject))
            ValuePanel.Children.Add(New Separator With {.Height = 1, .Opacity = 0})
        End If

    Next

End Function
```

I have tried this event that triggers whenever the user types into a ComboBox in the stackpanel.

```
Private Sub ValuePanel_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ValuePanel.PreviewKeyDown
    Dim myElement = e.OriginalSource

    Dim myVar = GetValue(myElement).GetType().GetProperty("PropertyName")

End Sub
```

But myElement is not a DependencyProperty and it cannot be cast to one.

Comment: @mm8 I realised I just had a typo, I meant ComboBox not TextBox, either way, I need to get the VariableName/PropertyName that the control has. So, this control that is the property of class VariableClass was created in the stackpanel : Public Property myNameTextBox As New ComboBox, when I click on the object in the listbox and then type in this ComboBox, I need to find out if its PropertyName is "myNameTextBox" or not. I know that these controls are directly linked to the selected object's properties because clicking between objects I noticed the values are being memorised.

Comment: Then you need to store the name somewhere. The `ComboBox` doesn't know which property it came from...

Comment: @mm8 but then how does it know to store the value it currently has for the selected object? It is definitely bound to the object in the listbox, because when I click other objects and come back to the one I had edited a combobox in, it knows, when debugging it I also see the values change!

Comment: @mm8 no, you misunderstand, as I stated in the question.. I have a listbox I fill with custom objects, then when the user clicks them, their properties that are WPF controls are created in a stackpanel, these WPF controls are bound to the selected object in that listbox (I confirmed this with DEBUG).

Comment: @mm8 I don't bind it, the binding happens automatically, check the Function AddPropertiesInStackPanel(myObject As Object) function for more info. I don't understand why the question is getting downvoted, it's pretty clear what the problem is and I provided both the code and storyline of the code. The function is adding properties of objects are WPF Controls, these WPF controls are directly linked to those objects, so when I change a value in those WPF controls, the parent objects themselves also update, there is a linkage somewhere and IDK where.

Comment: Nothing is clear. `AddPropertiesInStackPanel` adds children to a `StackPanel`. So what is your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240825/discussion-between-laurian-avrigeanu-and-mm8).

Comment: @mm8 ValuePanel.Children.Add(item.GetValue(myObject)) adds the property of the object to a stackpanel, this property is a WPF control of that object, the WPF controls I am talking about are 100% properties of the ListBox SelectedItem which is a custom object (VariableClass). When you edit this WPF Control, the properties of that ListBox SelectedItem update as well automatically.... So if this functionality exists between them... there has to be a way to find out the PropertyName of the ComboBox.. they're linked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control that raises the `PreviewKeyDown` doesn't know which propery of your custom object it "came" from. You can however store this information in the `Tag` property of the control, e.g.:

```
myNameTextBox.Tag = "myNameLabel"
```

...and then retrieve it in the event handler using this property:

```
Private Sub ValuePanel_PreviewKeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    Dim myElement = CType(e.OriginalSource, FrameworkElement)

    Dim propertyName = myElement.Tag.ToString()

End Sub
```